# Multiple display with a laptop

Tags: laptop, display, hdmi, lcd, vga

Is it possible that I can get two different displays when I hook my laptop to a Projecter /LCD via a HDMI or a VGA cable that, I am able to continue doing my work and let a certain be displayed on the VGA or HDMI port. Is any scenario possible Kindly guide.

Comment: Operating system? I think what you want is extend desktop, instead of clone desktop.

Comment: Windows XP or Windows 7. Both. Yes Extend a desktop, with different applications to be run and displayed only on respective desktop displays

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short, simple answer is yes. Most laptops with multiple video-out support the ability to "Extend your desktop" allowing you to span your Windows (or Linux) across multiple monitors.

Comment: Kindly walk me thriugh the procedure and the results I would have.

Comment: @aibk01 try this link: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Understanding-multiple-monitors

Comment: actually this one is better: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Move-windows-between-multiple-monitors